# Zend Framework auth suddenly stops working

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework, centos

I migrated a large site yesterday to a new machine. The new machine is running centos 6.3 with php 5.3 on zend.

Everything was running perfectly fine without issues. This morning my phone blows up with an issue that users cannot login. After looking at the errors, it appears they are unable to log in due to this error:

```
#0 /usr/share/php/Zend/Auth/Adapter/DbTable.php(286): Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable->_authenticateQuerySelect(Object(Zend_Db_Select))
#1 /usr/share/php/Zend/Auth.php(117): Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable->authenticate()
#2 /home/localsbest/public_html/application/default/models/Authent.php(50): Zend_Auth->authenticate(Object(Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable))
#3 /home/localsbest/public_html/application/default/controllers/AuthentController.php(232): Authent->__construct('john@gocrr.com', 'freedom7')
#4 /usr/share/php/Zend/Controller/Action.php(503): AuthentController->indexAction()
#5 /usr/share/php/Zend/Controller/Dispatcher/Standard.php(285): Zend_Controller_Action->dispatch('indexAction')
#6 /usr/share/php/Zend/Controller/Front.php(934): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http))
#7 /home/localsbest/public_html/public/index.php(46): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch()
#8 {main}
```

I've never seen this error before. Even worse, I can't think of ANYTHING I could have done to cause the issue. I was sleeping! Does anyone have any idea where I can begin to hunt this problem down?

- EDIT *

Also seeing this error:

```
The supplied parameters to Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable failed to produce a valid sql statement, please check table and column names for validity.
```

- EDIT

If it also helps, the app was running on PHP 5.2.4 and now it's running on 5.3.

Comment: You've posted the stack trace but not the actual error, which should appear above it in the logs. Is the 'The supplied parameters...' message in your edit the error message being generated? Also, what version of ZF? My best guess with limited info would be MySQL table corruption.

Comment: I was already starting to look at the db more closely and I pointed it to the old db and it worked. So you're right, something became corrupted. I'm in the process of redumping the db over and resyncing everything. Post an answer and I can accept. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment, my best guess here is MySQL table corruption. You could run `CHECK TABLE xxx` to see if this is the problem, and then `REPAIR TABLE xxx` if so. If you have the MySQL error log enabled you'll probably see something there. But copying over a fresh dump would fix it too.

It's unfortunate the Zend Auth adapter class seems to catch any exception and show the "The supplied parameters..." error, as this is masking the real cause of the issue.